# Retornar o valor total de itens calculados numa lista

Tags: microsoft-access

Eu tenho uma tabela com `Quant` e `Preço`.
No formulário, além desses campos, eu tenho o campo `Total = [Quant]*[Preço]`

Além disso, no formulário principal eu tenho o campo `SomaTotal = Soma([Total])`

Ou seja, a clássica soma de preços que todo mundo sabe fazer.

## Pergunta:

Como eu faço para colocar esse total numa lista de Vendas?

Ou seja, eu tenho esse total para cada venda, mas eu precisava de uma lista que me retornasse todas as vendas, e o total de cada uma delas.

Eu teria que fazer uma consulta aninhada?

[image: Captura de Tela]

<sup>A imagem é ilustrativa. Eu preciso dessa lista no **MS Access.**</sup>

Comment: Você está fazendo isso via SQL ou por outro meio? (desculpe a ignorância, não entendo nada de MS Access) Se for via SQL, procure por [`GROUP BY`](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx). Senão, tem [um artigo](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/access-help/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-HA010006894.aspx) que explica passo-a-passo como fazer isso usando o "Assistente de Relatório" (*Report Wizard*). P.S. eu postaria isso como resposta, mas como falei, ignorância total em Access, ia acabar só falando besteira...

Comment: #mgibsonbr a palavra GROUP BY me ajudou. Eu fiz uma consulta SQL: SELECT detVendas.id, Sum([Quant]*[Preco]) AS Total
FROM detVendas
GROUP BY detVendas.id; Valeu

Comment: @RegisdaSilva se vc quiser, pode adicionar o seu comentário como a resposta para a questão, e aceitar como resposta correta. Facilita para quem quiser pesquisar no futuro no site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz uma consulta SQL:

```sql
SELECT detVendas.id, Sum([Quant]*[Preco]) AS Total FROM detVendas GROUP BY detVendas.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

No MSAccess você pode criar campos e colocar que o valor deles seja igual a outro campo do formulário / relatório.

No seu caso, se entendi bem, você vai fazer um formulário que vai calculando o total de de 3 vendas, e depois quer que em outra parte do mesmo formulário apareça apenas o total de cada venda (como se fosse um resumo), e talvez o total geral (somando as 3 vendas), isto ?

Insira um método na propriedade AfterUpdate do seu total de cada venda (que tem valor 4044 e 2280, no seu exemplo) e faça com que ele atualize o outro campo.

Exemplo:

```vba
Private Sub TotalVenda1_AfterUpdate()

    Me.[TotalGeral1] = Me.[TotalVenda1]

End Sub
```